# Using Web Workers in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-worker

Trying to setup a basic web worker in Angular.

This is what I have:

```
      // Create a new
      const worker = new Worker('./transaction.worker', { type: 'module' });
      worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
      };
      worker.postMessage('hello');
      console.log("POSTED MESSAGE")
```

And inside the `transaction.worker` this:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  postMessage(response);
});
```

When I run the worker, it does execute the log statement `console.log("POSTED MESSAGE")`  and there are no errors, but the log statement  `console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);` does not get executed. At least it does not show up in the Chrome Dev Tools.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to stop the live reload and start it again, allowing the entire app to recompile.

When we generate a web worker, the `angular.json` configuration is updated, thus the entire app as the be recompiled. The Live Reload compilation will not pickup the configuration change.